# Android app freezes after scrolling a little

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

This scrollview freezes after a few seconds. How can I solve it? This works perfectly fine but it freezes after a while.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <AbsoluteLayout
      android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/acc_stngs"
      android:paddingTop="50dip"
      android:paddingBottom="50dip"
      >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="95dp"
            android:text="Name:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="85dp"
            android:layout_y="95dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="160dp"
            android:text="Surname:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="105dp"
            android:layout_y="160dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="280dp"
            android:text="E-mail:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="87dp"
            android:layout_y="280dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="380dp"
            android:text="Address:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="278dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_x="19dp"
            android:layout_y="450dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="630dp"
            android:text="Current Password:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="655dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="710dp"
            android:text="New Password:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="735dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="790dp"
            android:text="Confirm Password:"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="17dp"
            android:layout_y="815dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget46"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="17dp"
        android:layout_y="900dp"
        android:background="#ff990033"
        android:onClick="LogOutUser"
        android:text="Log Out"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget46"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="900dp"
        android:background="#ff000099"
        android:onClick=""
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you have any error to share or something? The scroll stop after what? Are you able to see something? Please help us help you

Comment: @GhostDerfel The page works perfectly fine, after scrolling it just doesn't get scrolled anymore. I get no errors or warnings about it.

Comment: so basically you can scroll down but when you stop scrolling the first time the scrollview just ignore your touch events?

Comment: We need to see some code and some logs, we need to see if there is anything in your code that would cause this.

Comment: Did you already tested to use linearlayout and see if works fine?